# Тонкая настройка JVM и терминал

Tags: java

Для тестирования нужно ограничить размер кучи в JVM, то есть 50 MB of JVM heap. Как это можно сделать ?
И второй вопрос, как нужно запустить прогу, чтобы в командной строке можно записать ключи как аргументы для main ?

Answer (score 3):

Запускаем

```
java -help
```

Получаем подсказку, из которой видно:

1. Аргументы передаются в командной строке в самом конце (необязательная часть `[args...]`)
2. Чтобы получить помощь по дополнительным опциям, нужно использовать опцию `-X`

Ок. Выполняем

```
java -X
```

Видими список опций для управления размером heap.

Comment: у меня вопрос как раз в том, какую консоль открыть? Я открываю стандартную консоль Windы cmd. А как там запустить мою программу на Java?

Comment: @stream2006 Мой ответ подходит к вашим условиям, но вот ваш стиль мышления не подходит. Если вы не знаете, как запустить вашу программу на Java, то задайте соответствующий вопрос. А еще лучше, потратьте время на изучение основ: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/win32.html

Answer (score 1):

-Xms size начальный размер хипа, -Xmx size максимальный размер хип